# Google Data Studio, how to get a sum of all Max or Min values

Tags: looker-studio

I am working with a data set where i have to get Min or Max for different text fields. My dataset can have thousands of rows so below is a simpler example. So I have 3 categories having multiple values and I can put this dataset in GDS to build a table where I select Category as dimention and Value as Max(Value) in metric.
Now I need to see the sum of all those values too. But like the pivot table in excel, the subtotal in GDS shows the Max out of all the max listed above. So instead of 65, it shows 30 in GDS. Is there a way I can get it to show the sum?

[image: Category]

Answer (score 2):

To reach the desired result you will need:

1. Make a data combination, not being necessary to insert a second base, just so that a current base is defined as a data combination.
2. In the combination use the Category dimension and define the Max Value metric. The combination is only necessary for the metric to be used in the table as a dimension (this is a property resulting from the combination of data).

[image]

3. Configure the table with the Category dimension and Include the metric with the Value sum option. Remember that now Value is the maximum value (as defined in the data combination).
4. Finally, display the Summary line. And the desired result is obtained

[image]